# What is the Fedora equivalent of the Debian build-essential package?

Tags: fedora, compiling, packaging

What is the Fedora equivalent of the Debian build-essential package?

Answer (score 190, accepted):

The closest equivalent would probably be to install the below packages:

```
sudo dnf install make automake gcc gcc-c++ kernel-devel
```

However, if you don't care about exact equivalence and are ok with pulling in a lot of packages you can install all the development tools and libraries with the below command.

```
sudo dnf groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"
```

On Fedora version older than 32 you will need the following:

```
sudo dnf groupinstall @development-tools @development-libraries
```

Comment: Better answer below for modern Fedora

Comment: `@development-tools` is not available on Fedora 32.

Comment: @AspiringDev `@development-tools` _are_ available, `@development-libraries` aren’t.

Comment: @JurajFiala not on Fedora 32 at least: `Module or Group '@development-tools' is not available. Error: Nothing to do.`

Comment: I confirm @development-tools is not available: Last metadata expiration check: 0:01:26 ago on Tue 25 Aug 2020 07:38:48 PM -05.
Module or Group '@development-tools' is not available.
Error: Nothing to do.

Comment: `sudo dnf groupinstall "Development Tools" "Development Libraries"` brilliant.

Comment: Fedora 36 -  `sudo dnf group install "C Development Tools and Libraries" "Development Tools"` works for me.

Comment: also `redhat-rpm-config` seems to be needed, although somehow strange

Answer (score 88):

For Fedora 23 and up to somewhere near Fedora 32. Also works in Fedora 38.

`dnf install @development-tools`

Installing `gcc` and `g++` might also be needed.

Comment: For what it's worth, this is a literal equivalent to `build-essential linux-headers-generic`; it only installs what's needed to compile software (like gcc and make) as well as kernel headers. Thanks!

Comment: My mistake; `linux-headers-generic` also requires Fedora package `linux-devel`.

Comment: I think the answer should be updated, since this is the better answer for modern versions of fedora.

Comment: I had to run `sudo dnf group install "C Development Tools and Libraries"`

Comment: `@development-tools` doesn't seem to include `gcc-c++`, so I also had to install the C Development group as mentioned by @davidtbernal